# Why is React saying "Invalid prop `children`"?

Tags: reactjs

I'm seeing this error in my console:

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ButtonRow`. Check the render method of `BookingForm`.

`ButtonRow` looks like this:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export function Left(props) {
    return <div className="left-col">{props.children}</div>;
}

export function Right(props) {
    return <div className="right-col">{props.children}</div>;
}

const LeftOrRight = PropTypes.oneOfType([Left, Right]);

export default class ButtonRow extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
            PropTypes.arrayOf(LeftOrRight),
            LeftOrRight,
        ]).isRequired,
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.children);
        let children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
        return <div className="row">
            {children.filter(c => c.type === Left)}
            {children.filter(c => c.type === Right)}
        </div>
    }
}

ButtonRow.Left = Left;
ButtonRow.Right = Right;
```

And I'm rendering it like this:

```
<ButtonRow>
    <ButtonRow.Left>
        xxx
    </ButtonRow.Left>
    <ButtonRow.Right>
        yyy
    </ButtonRow.Right>
</ButtonRow>
```

It's displaying exactly as I'd expect. How come it's failing validation? What should I be setting `propTypes` to?

Ideally I'd like to enforce one of:

- One `Left` child
- One `Right` child
- One `Left` and one `Right`

Nothing else should be accepted

Comment: just to take a step back. what good is your Left and Right Stateless Functions doing? meaning. they are identical. why even have them both? why not just have one that renders the same thing? looks like this is being over complicated.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Haven't finished writing them; they'll differ in a sec ;)

Comment: You may put a breakpoint on the line that emits a warning and use a call stack to find the exact place where the proptypes validation fails.

Comment: again. its just a class name. why not pass that as a conditional and render the same thing every time?

Comment: @JohnRuddell How would I enforce it then? And maybe I want to do some craziness down the road where I swap the left and right buttons for different OSes because Windows has OK on the right, Cancel on the left, Mac does something different...who knows, I'm just having fun with it and trying to figure out how propTypes works :) I'll try to add a breakpoint, but I'm using es6/webpack/babel; I'll see if I can even find the right place to put it.

Comment: @mpen it's trivial - in the chrome dev tools console there is a link on the right part of the message: it refers to the exact line. Just click it and put a breakpoint. Then refresh the page without changing anything in your code (so that the bundle stayed the same).

Comment: @zerkms http://i.imgur.com/q0fdga4.png Everything is just as I'd expect... I've got a Left and a Right. `PropTypes.arrayOf` should accept that shouldn't it?

Comment: "should accept that shouldn't it" --- that's why you need a debugger: now restart the stackframe (right click on the current one for the corresponding action) and step through the proptypes check to see why `error` happens.

Comment: @zerkms Well...thank you for teaching me how to use my debugger; didn't know you could restart stack frames. However, I still couldn't find where it went awry; too many levels. I did figure out the problem by looking at another example though...

Comment: @mpen "too many levels" --- that + asynchronicity, is what makes debugging react internals hard/painful (but improves debugging skills in general :-D)

Answer (score 6):

This answer is correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/41992473/1426788 but i'd like to share my experience with the same issue.

This error occurred for me when me when my wrapper component was rendering a single child rather than multiple:

For example:

```
<Foo>
  <Bar>
</Foo>
```

would throw a warning where

```
<Foo>
  <Bar>
  <Baz>
</Foo>
```

would not.

It appears that rendering a single child in react follows different semantics than rendering multiple children and PropTypes should be updated accordingly.

More info on available PropTypes here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes

Comment: That's not the case here. The issue is that `oneOfType` expects another PropType, not a React component class as arguments.

Comment: Right I meant to convey a scenario that triggered the warning for myself. Your answer is correct, I was adding to the conversation with another scenario for people googling the same warning. Let me update my response

Comment: Ah, okay. Fair enough :-)

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly my situation. I have a wrapper component that may be given single or multiple children. I now use the following in propTypes. 'children': PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.element,
  PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element),
 ]).isRequired,

Comment: "It appears that rendering a single child in react follows different semantics than rendering multiple children"

Thanks, I hate this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom re-usable prop-type like this:

```
export function childrenOf(...types) {
    let fieldType = PropTypes.shape({
        type: PropTypes.oneOf(types).isRequired,
    });

    return PropTypes.oneOfType([
        fieldType,
        PropTypes.arrayOf(fieldType),
    ]);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
export default class RadioMenu extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        children: WxTypes.childrenOf(RadioButton).isRequired,
    };

    ...
}
```